# How do I uninstall all rpms installed today with yum?

Tags: centos, fedora, redhat, rpm, yum

I am very familiar with

```
rpm -qa --last
```

and have found it to be very handy on certain occasions. However on this occasion I accidentally got a bit overzealous and installed a large yum group.

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
```

Is there an easy way to uninstall everything I just installed? Seems to me there should be some way to combine rpm query and rpm erase. i.e. piping the output from a query command into the remove command.

**Update:** based on user @rickhg12hs feedback

It was pointed out that I can see the transaction id with `yum history` which I did not know about. Here is what that looks like:

```
$ yum history

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
ID | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
69 |  <jds>                   | 2015-05-11 01:31 | Install        |    1   
68 |  <jds>                   | 2015-05-11 01:31 | Install        |    1   
67 |  <jds>                   | 2015-05-11 01:10 | I, U           |  210   
66 |  <jds>                   | 2015-05-05 12:41 | Install        |    1   
65 |  <jds>                   | 2015-04-30 17:57 | Install        |    2   
64 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-30 10:11 | Install        |    1   
63 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-30 10:11 | Install        |    1   
62 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-30 10:11 | Install        |    1 EE
61 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-30 10:11 | Install        |    1   
60 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-30 10:11 | Install        |    1   
59 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-30 09:58 | Install        |   19 P<
58 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-29 18:28 | Install        |    1 > 
57 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-29 18:28 | Install        |    1   
56 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-29 18:28 | Install        |    9   
55 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-29 18:28 | Install        |    3   
54 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-29 18:28 | Install        |    1   
53 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-29 18:27 | I, U           |    5   
52 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-29 18:27 | I, U           |    4   
51 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-29 18:27 | Install        |    1   
50 |  <ansible>               | 2015-04-29 18:27 | Install        |    1
```

and tada: There it is, a transaction id.

I want to uninstall from transaction id 67. So now that I am a bit wiser I have a new question.

### So how can I use the yum or rpm command to uninstall a transaction?

Note: it was also pointed out to me that I can do a

```
$ yum history info 67 |less

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Transaction ID : 67
Begin time     : Mon May 11 01:10:09 2015
Begin rpmdb    : 1012:bb05598315dcb21812b038a356fa06333d277cde
End time       :            01:13:25 2015 (196 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 1174:cb7855e82c7bff545319c38b01a72a48f3ada1ab
User           :  <jds>
Return-Code    : Success
Command Line   : groupinstall Additional Development
Transaction performed with:
   Installed     rpm-4.8.0-38.el6_6.x86_64                     @updates
   Installed     yum-3.2.29-60.el6.centos.noarch               @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.x86_64/6.6
   Installed     yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.x86_64/6.6
Packages Altered:
   Dep-Install GConf2-2.28.0-6.el6.x86_64                                @base
   Install     GConf2-devel-2.28.0-6.el6.x86_64                          @base
   Dep-Install ORBit2-2.14.17-5.el6.x86_64                               @base
   ... snip ...
```

I think this could prove quite helpful under certain circumstances.

Comment: close but no cigar: `sudo rpm -qa --qf '%{INSTALLTIME:date}: %{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n' |grep "Mon 11 May 2015"|cut -d ':' -f4 |xargs rpm --nodeps -e`

Comment: If you used `yum` to do all your installs, you should be able to use `yum history` to safely `undo` or `rollback` your transactions.  See `man yum` for the details.

Comment: Please show the output of `yum history`.  Do you see your transaction ID?  Does `yum history info your_transaction_ID` show all the packages that were installed?

Comment: @rickhg12hr I did not know about `yum history` ... yes I see the transaction where I altered 210 packages. yep: `yum history info 67` shows them all to me! so how do I uninstall a transaction?

Comment: Read `man yum` and decide whether `yum history undo` or `yum history rollback` is better suited to what you want.

Answer (score 2):

If you *uninstall* packages, then you run the risk of removing things that were already there, but happened to be upgraded.  As a rule, you should use `yum` (or equivalent) for managing packages, which allows you to *downgrade* a package.  This would remove new packages, and downgrade existing ones.  See for example [How to safely downgrade or remove glibc with yum and rpm](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/158973)

Selecting the names of packages to downgrade can be done using the output of `rpm -qa`, formatted to allow simple selection of the given date.  For instance (see *[CentOS: List the installed RPMs by date of installation/update?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/centos-list-the-installed-rpms-by-date-of-installation-update)*), you can list packages in the reverse-order of their install date using

```
rpm -qa --last
```

As a more elaborate approach, you can use the [`--queryformat`](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Docs/QueryFormat) option with the `:date` option to format the date exactly as you want (it uses [`strftime`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html)).

In either case, you can make a script to extract the package names from the output of `rpm`, and use those packages with `yum` (or even `rpm`) to manipulate as needed.

When doing a downgrade, there is one odd thing to keep in mind: that revises the install-date for packages to be the *current date* rather than a complete undo, by using the previous date.

Answer (score 1):

All packages installed in a single transaction have
an identical RPMTAG_INSTALLTID tag value.

Use

```
rpm -qa --qf '[%{name}\t%{installtid:date}\n]'
```

to find all packages that were installed as part of the yum group install.

Comment: that `installtid` is not showing up in the output.  running `rpm-4.8.0-38.el6_6` However: what I really want to know is how to uninstall all packages ( there are 210 of them ) from one transaction id. Is there a nifty rpm or yum command to do that?

Comment: It shows up as a date because suffixed with :date. Remove that and it will show up as a number

Answer (score 1):

Yum has provision for you to undo your command i.e. `yum history undo #blah`

In your case, to remove all packages you installed today you can run :

```
yum history undo 69
yum history undo 68
yum history undo 67
```